# Typescript recursive arrow function type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, types

I've got these two functions

```
  const renderEntry = (entry: NavigationEntryType, index: number): ReactElement => {
    const { display_name: displayName } = entry;

    const id = displayName.replace(' ', '');

    return <NavigationEntry key={id} index={index} displayName={displayName} id={id} moveEntry={moveEntry} />;
  };

  const iterateItems = <T extends NavigationEntryType[]>(items: T): T | ReactElement => {
    return items.map((item, index) => {
      if (item.items && item.items.length > 0) {
        return iterateItems(item.items);
      }

      return renderEntry(item, index);
    }
  );
```

I'm receiving an error on the return type of `iterateItems`:

```
Error:(33, 5) TS2322: Type '(NavigationEntryType[] | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>)[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | T'.
  Type '(NavigationEntryType[] | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>)[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

What should it be?

Tried with `T | ReactElement` but that doesn't work, I' very new to typescript tho.

Comment: I assume the return type is `NavigationEntry[]`. Why? Because by using `return items.map...` it's obvious, that you are returning an array and `renderEntry`, which is used to construct this new array, returns a `NavigationEntry`.

Comment: "I'm receiving an error" please supply details of this as part of your question. They're very helpful.

Comment: @spender added the error, you're right :)
@Paul well, `renderEntry` returns a `ReactElement`